Azure Elastic Job Use Credentials instead of Identity
We have an elastic jobs agent that has been running for some time now but recently started seeing every job failing consistenly.
We have used credentials in the past but it appears someone added an identity to to the agent and now every job returns wih the error:
Failed to determine members of SqlServerTarget (server name 'server-name', server location 'server-location'): Login failed for user 'token-identified principal'.
I beleieve this means the agent is attempting to use the UMI (User Managed Identities) to login to the DB instead of the credentials
I have deleted the identity but the error persists.
Please help how to I get the agent to use credentials again or turn of UMI.
THANKS!


Failed to determine members of SqlServerTarget (server name 'server-name', server location 'server-location'): Login failed for user 'token-identified principal'.

The error is causing because of your job agent is not able to authenticate with the server.
To database-scoped credentials to authenticate with elastic job agent;

Generate a job agent login or user in every destination database where the job is scheduled to execute. This login or user should have an identical name to the identity of the database-scoped credential used for the job, along with the same password as the database-scoped credential.
Connect to the master database of the logical server and create SQL authenticated login with the same name as the identity of the database-scoped credential for the job user, and the same password as the database-scoped credential for the job user.

CREATE LOGIN [job_user] WITH PASSWORD '<same_password_as_database-scoped_credential>'
GO


Connect to the output database and run the following example script for a user named  job_user:

CREATE USER [job_user] FROM LOGIN [job_user]; 


grant the required permissions to CREATE TABLE and INSERT data into that output table.

Reference :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-tutorial?view=azuresql#use-database-scoped-credentials
